# Passing an object containing an array to D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to pass the following data structure into D3, specifically the pie layout.

```
var myData = {
myValue : "foo",
myArray : [
    {animal : "cat", noise : "meow", cost : 200},
    {animal : "dog", noise : "woof", cost : 300}
  ]
}
```

I am unable to pass the array portion into d3 using dot notation, for example:

```
//Passing of data to pie omitted
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                  .value(function(d){
                    return d.myArray.cost;
                  });
```

Can someone supply a bl.ocks example or tutorial that works with this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're two code snippets don't seem to go together, so this might not be what you want.  Update with a complete, simplified (and working except for this problem) program.

That said: the [value accessor function of the pie layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#value) is the function that is called on *each element* of your array to access the number representing the size of that pie slice, not on the data object to extract the array.

You have to yourself extract the array from the complete data object before calling the pie function.  E.g., if your data objects are bound to separate pieChart `<g>` elements, you would use:

```
var pieSlices = pieChart.selectAll("path.pieSlices")
                   .data( function(d){return pie(d.array);} );
                   //`d` in a data function is the data joined to the parent;
                   //the function must return an array of data for children.
```

Comment: I'll update the example for posterity, but this is the exact bit of logic I was missing.